# Remove wacom from my system

Tags: uninstall, wacom

I purged the "xserver-xorg-input-wacom" package, yet the Wacom entries still appear in gnome-control-panel and my system menus.

How can I get rid of them?

Comment: I don't think you need to. Why don't you want it? If you are having problems with your graphics tablet, you need to edit the 50-wacom.conf file in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d

Comment: If you don't use a wakom anymore, it is annoying to get warnings lilke that the battery of your non-existent wacom is empty or such. So, uninstalling it is nice

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to remove wacom entries from the interface by renaming or deleting the `/usr/share/applications/gnome-wacom-panel.desktop` file.

To rename, run the following, then logout/login.

```
cd /usr/share/applications

sudo mv gnome-wacom-panel.desktop gnome-wacom-panel.desktop-renamed
```