# Problem with a touch screen in a HP Compaq TC4400

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, wacom, 16.04

I have a problem with my HP Compaq Tc4400 and the touch screen with a pen.

When I'm running Lubuntu 16.04 with my touchpad, the screen detects that I'm using the pen (that i'm not using) of the touch screen and moves the mouse!

How can I uninstall the Wacom driver (it manage the pen and the tactile mode of my screen)

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Possible answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79018/remove-wacom-from-my-system) Let me know if this works or not.

Comment: I'll try it as soon as the installation process answers me...

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall just xserver-xorg-input-wacom

> sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-wacom

This will remove just the xserver-xorg-input-wacom package itself.

Uninstall xserver-xorg-input-wacom and it's dependencies

> sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove xserver-xorg-input-wacom

This will remove the xserver-xorg-input-wacom package and any other dependant packages which are no longer needed.

Purging your config/data too
If you also want to delete your local/config files for xserver-xorg-input-wacom then this will work.

Caution! Purged config/data can not be restored by reinstalling the package.

> sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-wacom

Or similarly, like this xserver-xorg-input-wacom

> sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove xserver-xorg-input-wacom

Pasted from:
[This](http://www.installion.co.uk/ubuntu/trusty/main/x/xserver-xorg-input-wacom/uninstall/index.html)